# I need your opinion on CSS optimization

Tags: css, optimization

Lately I’m reading a lot of CSS optimization, and I notice that almost every article, recommend to put ALL your styles in ONE file.

I understand the thinking behind this, but this is practical? I mean I’m working in a fairly large project and by now I have a huge amount of styles. I think it will be very difficult to maintain with everything in one file.

My question is: the performance gain is that big to justify the complexity of having all in ONE file?

Thanks!

Edgar.

***UPDATE***

**Just to clarify**, I’m sure about the need to optimize the CSS. Actually, I have a process in place that minimize and compress the CSS files, and I do everything that I can to not repeat myself.

My doubt is exclusive about the practice of using one big file vs multiple files.

Let’s put this example:

My application has multiple modules, for example: contacts, projects, accounting, HHRR, etc.

I have one CSS file for each module, plus a couple of other general CSS files like: reset, layout, forms and so on.

When I’m using the CONTACTS module, I load the general files plus the contact.CSS file. I skip the 
rest of the CSS because they are not needed.

Now to the Math, let’s say that each CSS file is around 10KB,

**My current way:**

- About 50kb in general files About 5
- downloads request in general files
- About 10k in customer file One
- download request.

This is a total of about 60kb and 6 download request.

**The one file Method:**

- About  120kb (all the files together including styles that are not used at the moment) in one file
- One download request.

So, in your opinion, **the beneficial gain** of using one big file and only one download request, justify all the extra work of implementing a method of combining all the files together and all that hassle?

Answer (score 3):

For development, keep them separate.  CSS can quickly become a nightmare.  For production you should build in a process to combine, minify and compress all your files into one.

Answer (score 1):

Do both. Develop in multiple files, then just have a process which combines, compresses and minifies (removes comments, spaces, etc) them into one file when you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

It's a great idea to compress your CSS like that, as it saves bytes and makes the page load faster.

When you *develop* your site, of course don't minify the code. It's pointless, as your local webserver is as fast as can be. But when you *deploy* your site, minify the code. It saves you bandwidth and makes your site more responsive for the end user.

Here's a sample chunk of CSS that I would use:

```
/*  33 characters */
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

When compressed, it's a bit smaller (`81%` of the original size):

```
/* 27 characters */
body{background-color:red;}
```

You can make a script to compress the CSS, as you shouldn't do this by hand. Google "css minifiers" and I bet you'll find a ton.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a performance gain so much as a *bandwidth* gain. Each file that the browser must fetch represents about 200 extra bytes. You can have a program that combines multiple CSS files into one for deployment, but most CSS minifiers will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I`m surprised that nobody mention one very obvious reason to do that.

In a big site, you will have many elements to load, especially visual elements - images. Think about how many files your site is loading. You can load a **limited number** of files from a single domain at once. And CSS is bringing some background images and sprites. There is no point loading 2, 3 or more CSS file.

Minification as Blender suggests is a bonus to your bandwidth. 2K is more is noting for a single user, but multiplied by 1 000 or 10 000 is a lot. And if you minify a CSS, what about the HTML? I haven`t seen so many pages with minified HTML!